# UUID interop with c# code

Tags: c#, java

Can c# donet generate same UUID for following java code? if so how? i tried GUID but didn't work!

Text:

```
String cleartext = "CN=CompanyName;mac=some mac;@host=somehost;email=admin@somedomain.com;issued=01/01/20013;expire=12/12/2013";
```

Java code:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

C# code:

```
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cleartext);
        Guid uid = new Guid(b);
        Console.Write(uid.ToString());
```

REF
[Earlier discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021045/generating-serial-or-hex-code-for-product-licensing)

Comment: Can you post the value of `cleartext`?

Comment: Are you meaning that you want to create a `Guid`/`UUID` object with the contents of an existing UUID, or are you trying to get them to generate the same UUID? I don't see a preexisting UUID anywhere, and that's the .NET constructor wants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all you need is the same UUID string (and not actual UUID/Guid objects), this C# method will return the same value as Java's `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])` method.

```
public static string NameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] input)
{
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(input);
    hash[6] &= 0x0f;
    hash[6] |= 0x30;
    hash[8] &= 0x3f;
    hash[8] |= 0x80;
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
    return hex.Insert(8, "-").Insert(13, "-").Insert(18, "-").Insert(23, "-");
}
```

C# Example

```
string test = "test";
Console.Out.WriteLine(NameUUIDFromBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)));

Output:
098f6bcd-4621-3373-8ade-4e832627b4f6
```

Java Example

```
UUID test = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("test".getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(test);

Output:
098f6bcd-4621-3373-8ade-4e832627b4f6
```

**Edit**: I know it's after the fact, but this will produce an actual `Guid` object with the same value. Just incase anyone wants it.

```
public static Guid NameGuidFromBytes(byte[] input)
{
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(input);
    hash[6] &= 0x0f;
    hash[6] |= 0x30;
    hash[8] &= 0x3f;
    hash[8] |= 0x80;

    byte temp = hash[6];
    hash[6] = hash[7];
    hash[7] = temp;

    temp = hash[4];
    hash[4] = hash[5];
    hash[5] = temp;

    temp = hash[0];
    hash[0] = hash[3];
    hash[3] = temp;

    temp = hash[1];
    hash[1] = hash[2];
    hash[2] = temp;
    return new Guid(hash);
}
```

Comment: Nice!  `+1` for putting this together.

Comment: Was looking at what Guid produced and I noticed that the difference was just that some of the bytes were swapped. So I've added a method for creating an actual Guid as well, just if anyone needs it.

Comment: Is there anyway to get back original input text with this MD5? i guess not huh?

Comment: No, MD5 is a one way hashing algorithm. Reversing it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This code is definitely not going to work with .NET.

The `Guid(Byte[])` constructor *must* [take in 16 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx) (as Guids are 128 bits), otherwise it will throw an ArgumentException.  Your string is much more than 16 bytes.

However, with that said, C# and Java will *still* not produce the same UUIDs using the same 16 bytes passed into the constructor.  In Java, you can pass in any arbitrary number of bytes into the `UUID` constructor and it will create a hash of those bytes.  In other words:

In C#:

```
Guid g = new Guid(new Byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16});
Console.WriteLine(g);
```

Will produce a different value than:

```
UUID u = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16});
System.out.println(u);
```

...in Java.

You could probably implement .NET's `Byte[16]` constructor in Java, or implement Java's hash constructor in .NET, but I would suggest using a string representation of your UUID across both platforms, for example, `"190c4c10-5786-3212-9d85-018939108a6c"`.

If you're trying to create a *hash* from a string, you might want to check into the MD5 class.  You'd want something like:

```
var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cleartext);
byte[] hashBytes  = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
```

MD5 is a standard algorithm and will produce the same hash for the same string in both .NET and Java.

Comment: That Java factory method takes a byte string, MD5 hashes it, runs it through a mangler, and then sets the appropriate flags to label it as a name-based UUID. See section 14 of [the UUID doc](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667-200409-S/en) for the algorithm.

Comment: @chrylis - Are you saying Java's `UUID(byte[])` constructor and .NET's `GUID(byte[])` constructor will produce different UUIDs for the same 16 bytes?  If that's the case, this person might be best off representing the UUID with a string.

Comment: No, Java has no `UUID(byte[])` constructor. I understand .NET's `(byte[])` constructor to "reconstitute" an existing UUID from its byte representation (basically wrapping the byte array); the [corresponding Java constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#UUID(long,%20long)) takes two `long`s. `nameUUIDFromBytes` follows the algorithm in section 14 to turn an arbitrary string (such as a DN) into a UUID with the flags set to indicate "this UUID was generated from a name".

Answer (score 0):

If you want interoperability don't depend on code that's not under your control. It could change with each Java version or implementation.

You could take the way that is used

```
/**
 * Static factory to retrieve a type 3 (name based) {@code UUID} based on
 * the specified byte array.
 *
 * @param  name
 *         A byte array to be used to construct a {@code UUID}
 *
 * @return  A {@code UUID} generated from the specified array
 */
public static UUID nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        throw new InternalError("MD5 not supported");
    }
    byte[] md5Bytes = md.digest(name);
    md5Bytes[6]  &= 0x0f;  /* clear version        */
    md5Bytes[6]  |= 0x30;  /* set to version 3     */
    md5Bytes[8]  &= 0x3f;  /* clear variant        */
    md5Bytes[8]  |= 0x80;  /* set to IETF variant  */
    return new UUID(md5Bytes);
}
```

> [source](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes%28byte%5b%5d%29)

and copy it into your code. Create exactly that in other languages as well and your problem should be gone.

In case "type 3 (name based) UUID" is a standard where the result is exactly specified, you could skip copying it in Java since implementation should never return a different result. It's likely that you will find implementations for other languages as well and don't need to port it by hand.

Comment: The implementation of name-based UUID generation is an implementation of a specification down to individual bits; it's not going to change with the whims of the platform vendor any more than the implementation of MD5 is.

Comment: Good to know, a "type 3" UUID could mean a lot of things and I was not sure what exactly. For example having just those few bits set in a specific way.