# UUID to GUID in Android

Tags: java, c#, android, uuid, guid

Im remaking a container from c# to Android studio in java, and i need the uuid variable on android to have the same value as in the guid in c#, obviously passing the same parameters.
I would like to know a solution or maybe an alternative to the android UUID, but still, it should return the same value as GUID if given the same parameter.

For example if the payload is [1,2,3,4],tagId in cs would have a value of "abc",i want tagId to return the same value in Java.

This is the one in .cs:

```
string tagId = new Guid(payload).ToString();
```

This is the code in java:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(payload);
String tagId = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: See "[UUID interop with c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023109)"